# Should Token Auth service return null or 401?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, api-auth

I am working on JWT Authentication service that needs to provide JWT token to Angular client app and I have following dilemma:

What service should return in case bad credentials are provided:

1. **{token: null}**, or
2. **401 Not Authorized** Http message

Does that make any difference when security is in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service can return both text message and 401 header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: application/json
{
"error": "unauthorized"
}
```

A php can make:

```
<? echo json_encode("error" = > "Not Authorized");
      http_response_code(401);
      exit ;
?>
```

Sometimes I prefer even make a return 404 from the server, a not authorized to the browser can say the caller is in the good way even sending bad token

Comment: Yes, why it should be divided :) Thanks!